# How to generate schema-less avro files using apache avro?

Tags: java, apache, avro

I am using Apache avro for data serialization. Since, the data has a fixed schema I do not want the schema to be a part of serialized data. In the following example, schema is a part of the avro file "users.avro".

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.setName("Alyssa");
user1.setFavoriteNumber(256);
User user2 = new User("Ben", 7, "red");
User user3 = User.newBuilder()
         .setName("Charlie")
         .setFavoriteColor("blue")
         .setFavoriteNumber(null)
         .build();

// Serialize user1 and user2 to disk
File file = new File("users.avro");
DatumWriter<User> userDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<User>(User.class);
DataFileWriter<User> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<User (userDatumWriter);
dataFileWriter.create(user1.getSchema(), new File("users.avro"));
dataFileWriter.append(user1);
dataFileWriter.append(user2);
dataFileWriter.append(user3);
dataFileWriter.close();
```

Can anyone please tell me how to store avro-files without schema embedded in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://thetechsolo.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/apache-avro-schema-less-serialization-how-to/) you find a comprehensive how to in which I explain how to achieve the schema-less serialization using Apache Avro. 
A companion test campaign shows up some figures on the performance that you might expect.

The [code is on GitHub](https://github.com/hailpam/avro-benchmark): example and test classes show up how to use the Data Reader and Writer with a Stub class generated by Avro itself.

Comment: Using the approach you described in your code is it possible to specify a codec? I.e. generate schemaless Avro that is, for example, deflate compressed?

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable.

Given an encoder, you can use a DatumWriter to write data directly to a ByteArrayOutputStream (which you can then write to a java.io.File).

Here's how to get started in Scala (from [Salat-Avro](https://github.com/Banno/salat-avro)):

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null)
encoder.write(myRecord, encoder)
```